# Having trouble changing event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, bots, irc

It's for my irc bot, and I am trying to change the message receiver event to be linked to the method in my other class.

```
 private static void client_Connected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        
            gamebot.LocalUser.JoinedChannel += LocalUser_JoinedChannel;
            gamebot.LocalUser.MessageReceived += LocalUser_MessageReceived;
        
        
    }
    
   // private static void newmessage(object sender, IrcChannelEventArgs e)
   // {
   //     e.Channel.MessageReceived += Hangman.MessageReceivedHangman;
        
  //  }
    private static void LocalUser_JoinedChannel(object sender, IrcChannelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Channel.MessageReceived += Channel_MessageReceived;
        Console.WriteLine("Joined " + e.Channel + "\n");
    }
```

Just not sure how to get the channeleventargs outside of a method, so I can change the event.  The commented method shows sort of what i need.

```
public static void MessageReceivedHangman(object sender, IrcMessageEventArgs e)
    {
```

That is the method in a different class i would like to have execute when a message is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what would be best here, as you have provided so little context. All we really know is that you have one class (call it `class A`) handling specific events, and another class (call it `class B`) that wants to be able to handle events the first class already knows about.

Based on that, there are at least a couple of possibilities that might work for you.

**Option #1:**

Expose the "joined" event so that the second class can receive the same notifications and subscribe to the channel's event:

```
class JoinedChannelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Channel Channel { get; private set; }

    public JoinedChannelEventArgs(Channel channel) { Channel = channel; }
}

class A
{
    public static event EventHandler<JoinedChannelEventArgs> JoinedChannel;

    private static void LocalUser_JoinedChannel(object sender, IrcChannelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Channel.MessageReceived += Channel_MessageReceived;
        Console.WriteLine("Joined " + e.Channel + "\n");

        EventHandler<JoinedChannelEventArgs> handler = JoinedChannel;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, new JoinedChannelEventArgs(e.Channel);
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    static void SomeMethod()
    {
        A.JoinedChannel += A_JoinedChannel;
    }

    private static void A_JoinedChannel(object sender, JoinedChannelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Channel += MessageReceivedHangman;
    }
}
```

**Option #2:**

Expose the "message received" event instead:

```
class A
{
    public static event EventHandler<IrcMessageEventArgs> AnyChannelMessageReceived;

    public static void Channel_MessageReceived(object sender, IrcMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Whatever other code you had here, would remain

        EventHandler<IrcMessageEventArgs> handler = AnyChannelMessageReceived;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, e);
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    static void SomeMethod()
    {
        A.AnyChannelMessageReceived += MessageReceivedHangman;
    }
}
```

It's not clear from your post whether having the sender of the original event is important. If it is, then IMHO `Option #1` is better, as it provides direct access to the event. However, you could modify `Option #2` so that it passed `sender` to the handler (in `Channel_MessageReceived()`), instead of the `null` that's in the example (the `null` is more idiomatic for a `static event`, but not mandatory).

If neither of those options work for you, please provide better context. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.